# How to plot normal distribution-like histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability

I have data like [A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,D,D,D,...]

And I convert it into numerical list like   [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,...]

Each element has its frequency, for example, A shows up 3 times

I try to plot histogram and I get like this
[image]

Third element (probably C as character) shows up most often.

And I would like to place "third element vertical bar" in the center
And next to that center, I would like to place second and third frequent element to draw normal distribution-like arrangement.

In conclusion, I would like to see whether distribution of data has normal distribution shape or not
I checked this by using QQ plot but I also would like to see this in histogram plot using actual data

Comment: No, this distribution _is not_ normal at all. You can't just put the bars in certain places to make it look normal because that would mess up he meaning of the X axis.

Comment: Really? I thought data could follow the normal distribution if I move and arrange data for data to have normal distribution. For example, I thought if frequency of third element is located in center, and so on. I think I could think like that way, cause order of element like (A,B,C or B,C,A) is not important. Feature which looks important is "frequency", isn't it?

Comment: not at all. You can arrange the bars however you want, but only one particular arrangement (with the values of the X axis increasing and actually having a meaning) will mean "the normal distribution". If you could just rearrange the bars (and also stretch them upwards with disregard to the Y axis), you would be able to turn _any_ distribution into normal. But again, that would make the graph nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well what your goal is, I would recommend you to use the `distplot` function from seaborn. You will get both distribution and hist !

Comment: seaborn.distplot() didn't change the order of element to form data distribution (frequency distribution) to look normal distribution. But seaborn.distplot() just added smooth line plot looking 3 Gaussian normal distribution like mixture model. I think I'm thinking something incorrectly

Comment: Thanks. That function works better for data with large deviations than plt.hist() and plt.plot()

Answer (score 1):

You have asked so many questions in a single post. I will answer the one regarding plotting frequency of occurrence. Suppose your list has strings. You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module to compute the frequencies. You can then directly plot the frequencies and items using `plt.plot()`

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst = ['A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','E', 'E','E','E']

counts = Counter(lst)
plt.bar(counts.keys(), counts.values())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's useful way of plotting data for histogram.